# regex: replace matched text with output of method it's passed to

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file that's marked up like this:

```
Old McDonald had a <:farm/101:>
```

When the program reading through this text file hits this tag, it passes `farm/101` to a method that converts the tag to appropriate HTML code, depending on what sort of tag is passed. In this case, the word farm needs to be turned into a hyperlink, with 101 as its HREF. This is done in the `parseTag()` method, which is called as follows:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<:(.+?):>");        
Matcher tagMatch = pattern.matcher(in);

while (tagMatch.find()) {
    String parsed = parseTag(tagMatch.group(1);
    // replace tagMatch.group(0) with parsed
}
```

I then want to replace the entire tag with the output of that method. I've thought about doing something like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<:");    
String split = pattern.split(in);    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    if (i%2 == 0) sb.append(split[i]);
    else sb.append(parseTag(split[i]);
} 
String final = sb.toString();
```

`final` here would give me what I want, but this seems messy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` methods from `Matcher` instance.

Try

```
StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
while (tagMatch.find()) {
    //this will add text to buffer with replaced matched part
    tagMatch.appendReplacement(sb, parseTag(tagMatch.group(1)));
}
tagMatch.appendTail(sb);//to add rest of input after last replacement

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```